# Michael Hartl Chap 12 Password Reset redirects to homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

When the reset password link is sent through email, it does not seem to work. Clicking on it results in a redirect to the homepage due to:

> Filter chain halted as :valid_user rendered or redirected

Here is valid_user

```
# Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

PasswordsResetsController

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1)

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?                  # Case (3)
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)          # Case (4)
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'                                     # Case (2)
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

   # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

  # Converts email to all lower-case.
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end

end
```

I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this. When I remove the authenticated? portion of the code in valid_user method, it is still redirecting to homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was testing this using a user I created and did not go through the "activation" method because of the way I created the user. I tested with a user going through the sign up process on the website and it works.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve the issue. Consider accepting your own answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/249307

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have `before_filter :valid_user` in your `application_controller.rb`. If so, try adding a condition to `valid_user` that prevents checking for authentication and activation. For example, you could adjust the following method to suit your needs:

```
def valid_user
  unless controller_name == "password_resets"
    unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
            @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

If you have `before_filter :valid_user` in your `password_resets_controller.rb`, you could just remove it, since the use case includes: the user will not be authenticated while trying to reset his/her password.

Comment: That seems like a good workaround. I feel like I'm missing something with that. Wouldn't that cause a security flaw? And shouldn't it be authenticated because the reset token matches the digest?

Comment: Good questions. I haven't read anything from Hartl and didn't consider the token was something other than an ID. Using something like JWT for the reset token is smart.